# allowing sub grid with multiple entries in CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2016

I want to create a sub grid that allows users to enter new entity.
It should have fields where user can click and enter data

Is it possible to have one in CRM

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not how Dynamics CRM works natively but there are [third party add-on solutions](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=CRM%202016%20inline%20editing) to provide inline editing features.

CRM online 2015 and 2016 now have an "edit in excel" feature which also provides similar functionality.